# Is this WSP uninstallation script complete?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, workflow, wsp

I am using the following script for uninstallation of a wsp workflow feature. Please can someone check and confirm that it contains all the required steps for the uninstallation or not.

I am doubtful because when i run this uninstallation script and install the new version of the wsp; the workflow still behaves similar to what it did with the previous installation (means the new behavior is not shown by the workflow) so i think i might b doing something wrong in the uninstallation because the previous version of workflow is not completely removed from the document library....

```
     @SET serverName="http://myservername/"
@SET TWELVEDIR="c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\"
@SET STSADM="C:\SP\SP\stsadm"

REGEDIT /S Previous_Settings.reg


%STSADM% -o retractsolution -name MoveToFolder.wsp -immediate
%STSADM% -o deletesolution -name MoveToFolder.wsp



%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs


%STSADM% -o deactivatefeature -name MoveToFolder -url %serverName%
%STSADM% -o uninstallfeature -name MoveToFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the order is incorrect , you should be:

```
%STSADM% -o deactivatefeature -name MoveToFolder -url %serverName%
%STSADM% -o uninstallfeature -name MoveToFolder 
%STSADM% -o retractsolution -name MoveToFolder.wsp -immediate
%STSADM% -o deletesolution -name MoveToFolder.wsp

%STSADM% -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Also, Have you tried running an IISReset between the uninstall and the install?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from removing the package before deactivating the features, that looks complete enough. However, deactivating a feature will not necessarily remove everything that was installed by that feature. Code will not update until iis restarts, and anything that was copied into a list instance will stay there. Also, any v1 workflows that were serialized earlier will remain unchanged.